# SmartGWT - ListGrid cells vertical

Tags: java, smartgwt

I'm new in SmartGwt but I'm studying. I have a method for create an ListGrid. How can I align the columns vertically?

For example (my code show this):

```
c1 | c2 | c3 | c4 | c5 |
v1 | v2 | v3 | v4 | v5 |
```

and I want:

```
c1 | v11 | v12 | v13 | ...
c2 | v21 | v22 | v23 | ...
c3 | v31 | v32 | v33 | ...
. 
.
.
```

There's a way for do this? Thanks for help.

My Code:

```
public ListGrid createTableTest() {

    ListGrid tableTest = new ListGrid();
    tableTest.setWidth("80%");
    tableTest.setHeight("80%");
    tableTest.setShowAllRecords(true);

    ListGridField c1Column = new ListGridField("c1", "C1");
    ListGridField c2Column = new ListGridField("c2", "C2");
    ListGridField c3Column = new ListGridField("c3", "C3");
    ListGridField c4Column = new ListGridField("c4", "C4");

    tableTest.setFields(c1Column, c2Column, c3Column, c4Column);

    return tableTest;
}
```

Comment: then why are you using ListGrid?

Comment: ListGrid is designed to have no of rows with common header. Do you have single row?

Comment: @Braj No, I don't have. This is just a example, I'll have more rows. Do you have another suggestion of widget? I'm searching some examples in SmartGWT showcase. Thanks for attention.

Comment: how do you want to display it in case of more rows?

Comment: @Braj I want display: c1 | value 1 | value 2 | value 3 [...]. I just want display my widget vertically. Basically turn rows in column, and columns in rows. Thanks again.